# disable kafka logs clojure

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, clojure

I'm trying to disable Kafka logs in Clojure e.g.

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 2.6.0
```

to at least ERROR level to no avail. I'm using Logback and have set logback.xml under resources to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="kafka" level="OFF"/>
</configuration>
```

This is my project config btw:

```
[[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
 [net.mikera/core.matrix "0.62.0"]
 [distributions "0.1.2"]
 [clj-time "0.15.2"]
 [incanter/incanter-charts "1.9.3"]
 [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.3.1"]
 [environ "1.1.0"]
 [ring/ring-core "1.5.0"]
 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.5.0"]
 [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
 [metosin/compojure-api "1.1.9"]
 [clj-http "2.3.0"]
 [org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams "2.6.0"]
 [fundingcircle/jackdaw "0.7.2"]
 [com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind "2.10.0"]
 [ring-cors "0.1.13"]
 [ch.qos.logback/logback-classic "1.2.3"]]
```

Any ideas what might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the above configuration is just fine.  After a new session it worked just great. No kafka messages.  The previous configuration must have been cached somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's either a dependencies problem or an issue with the configuration file not being packaged in the expected location.

- In your `project.clj` I only see one dependency for logback. Try adding the extra dependencies mentioned in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/logback#maven) and see if makes any difference
- I think it's most likely that the file is not being found at runtime, thus a default configuration is used instead (that's why you won't see the changes you expect). Check if the `logback.xml` file can be found along with the class files and not in a separate subfolder.